# MS.Access VBA - Error 3061: Too Few Parameters.Expected 2

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, crosstab

I'm new to VBA. Right now, I want to create editable crosstab table using temp table. I have problem when I want to update the normalize table based on edited data. When I run my codes, I get this error, Error 3061: Too Few Parameters.Expected 2.Can somebody help me to check my codes? Thanks in advance

```
Public Sub Normalize()
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
On Error GoTo EH

'delete existing data from temp table
CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM tblNormalize;", dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

'get a recordset of the column headers
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT newvalue FROM Table1;")
Debug.Print
rs.MoveFirst
Do While rs.EOF = False

' "un" crosstab the data from crosstab table into Normalize table
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblNormalize (product, spec, descr,newvalue, Rate )" &  Chr(10) & _
"SELECT product,spec,descr, " & rs.Fields("newvalue") & ", [" & rs.Fields("newvalue") & "]" & Chr(10) & _
"FROM tblCrosstab;", dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges

Debug.Print rs.Fields("newvalue")
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

'update the original normalized dataset

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblNormalize INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON (tblNormalize.newvalue = t1.newvalue) " & _
" AND (tblNormalize.product = t1.product) AND (tblNormalize.spec = t1.spec) " & _
" AND (tblNormalize.descr = t1.descr)" & _
" SET Table1.Rate = tblNormalize.Rate;", dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges


Exit Sub

EH:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Error"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a world of hurt for yourself. Apart from that, this:

```
"INSERT INTO tblNormalize (product, spec, descr,newvalue, Rate )" &  Chr(10) & _
"SELECT product,spec,descr, " & rs.Fields("newvalue") & ", [" & rs.Fields("newvalue") & "]" & Chr(10) & _
"FROM tblCrosstab;"
```

Is going to come out all wrong.

Try:

```
"INSERT INTO tblNormalize (product, spec, descr,newvalue, Rate )" & _
" SELECT product,spec,descr, " & rs.Fields("newvalue") & ", [" _
& rs.Fields("newvalue") & "] FROM tblCrosstab;"
```

Also, use Debug.Print to write the string to the immediate window (Ctrl+G) and check if it works in the query design window. That error is usually due to misspelling of missing fields (columns).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I run the code again and the one that giving me error is the update statement. I don't know what is wrong with my code. Is it because of inner join?

Comment: Probably not. Why not try debug.print as I suggested? It will give you `UPDATE tblNormalize INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON (tblNormalize.newvalue = t1.newvalue)  AND (tblNormalize.product = t1.product) AND (tblNormalize.spec = t1.spec)  AND (tblNormalize.descr = t1.descr) SET Table1.Rate = tblNormalize.Rate;` Paste the line into SQL view of the query design window in MS Access and see what it tells you.

Comment: Hi Remou, thanks a lot for your help. My codes is working now :)